# Who is the best way to make a function have use in the same view 3 segmentedController, when selected one and show result

Tags: ios, swift

i have 3 UISegmentedControl in one UIView, i need to make some cals when the user select one UISegmentedControl, for this i try to use

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedController1: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedController2: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedController3: UISegmentedControl!
```

The code for first segmentedController1 is ok use:

```
let segmendIndex1 = segmentedController1.selectedSegmentIndex

if segmendIndex1 == 0 {

        let convertedValue = textFieldVal * untDollars

        //Parseo a String

        let initValue = String(format: "%.2f", textFieldVal)
        let endValue = String(format: "%.2f", convertedValue)


        resultadoLbl.text = "\(initValue) EUR = \(endValue) USD"

    } else if segmendIndex1 == 1 {

        let convertedValue = textFieldVal * unitEuros

        let initValue = String(format: "%.2f", textFieldVal)
        let endValue = String(format: "%.2f", convertedValue)

        resultadoLbl.text = "\(initValue) USD = \(endValue) EUR "
}
```

but when i select the second segmentedController2 is no ready.

who the best way to make this use If ....Else IF etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set tag property of all the three segmentcontrol and in the same method use switch case to differentiate them.

Comment: Ok Deepak, but now i delete one segmentedControl of three, is perfect now, i have use only IF ELSE in the practice.   thanks for your answer is ok now.